# How to get ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated in Window 8 store application

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, simulator, application-lifecycle

I want to simulate `ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated` state.

I am doing following
1. Launching the app
2. Navigating to Desktop, waiting for App to be in suspended state
3. Killing the app using End Task from Task Manager.

This application is used for a demonstration, and previously it was in Consumer preview. At that time, above steps worked good.

Now, in Windows 8 RTM, using above steps, `ApplicationExecutionState` is coming to be `NotRunning`.

I want to know how to the `Terminated` state?

I am already aware of following
1. By using simulator, First getting the app suspended, and then logging off from simulator.
2. By putting memory pressure in windows. This way the app will automatically get terminated. Problem is that I do-not know, how to put memory pressure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this Microsoft forum question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/63519d67-7eb5-4f6b-be4f-a6d064830d3f):

Terminated means that the app was first suspended, and then the user Session ended normally.

To simulate this in the debugger, you can run your app in the simulator and then trigger a suspend (Debug, Trigger Suspend).  Then you can log off of the simulator.  You can then fire up the simulator again in the debugger and see you hit the condition that you came from a previous state of 'Terminated'.

Alternatively, you can use the tool available At [winrt.codeplex.com](http://winrt.codeplex.com)

[Update: 2013-03-11 @ 11:02PST]

It's important to understand that in the [Windows 8 App Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx), the [`ApplicationExecutionState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.activation.applicationexecutionstate%28v=win.10%29.aspx) enumeration indicates the state of the app last time the process exited (via several objects' `PreviousExecutionState` property ).

The only way to simulate this state is to suspend your app, log-off and log back in again and restart the app or you could simulate a system under load by using/writing an app that can consume a considerable portion of the available physical RAM, forcing Windows to try and reclaim resources by force-terminating suspended apps.

To stress your machine out and consume large amounts of memory etc., you could use the consume.exe command-line app that comes in the Windows SDK or use [James McCaffrey's EatMem tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163613.aspx#S4).

Comment: I forgot to mention, that I have checked the Microsoft Forum question. I have yet to explore winrt.codeplex.com, but it looks promising.

Comment: [winrtdebug](winrt.codeplex.com) is not working in Win 8 RTM. Seems like it was compiled for some earlier versions, and not updated later. Is there any other way??

Comment: Updated the answer above with additional clarification.

Comment: I tried, consume.exe and this made OS unresponsive (needed to restart). EatMem tool is not working, through fatal exception.
Is there some other nice tool, that is good for demo (of eating physical memory), and does not take system down??

Comment: Any app that consumes large amounts of memory will stress the machine and cause it to slow considerably. Thus Consume is doing its job as expected. Try reducing the amount of memory you're asking Consume to eat - aim to eat enough to force the OS to start terminating apps, but not to hang completely.

Comment: I created a small exe that eats the memory, and this caused the app to terminate (from suspended state). Though this stressed the machine, after 2-3 min, the machine performance is restored.

Answer (score 2):

To trigger `Suspend and shutdown` as well as other process lifetime management events during debugging, use the `Debug Location` toolbar in Visual Studio. Next to the `Process` dropbox there's a dropdown button containing the above mentioned command:

[image: Process lifecycle management commands]

There's no need to use the simulator for this to work. You can run the app on your local machine just as well.

You can read more about this and the other commands in the dropdown button in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh974425.aspx).

Comment: This has dependency over Visual studio.